# Добавить студента без аватарки

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

Я написал проект где можно добавлять студента через браузер и он его хранит в MySQL. Он у меня хорошо все добавляет имя, фамилию, аватарку. Но когда я хочу просто добавить имя и фамилию он выбрасывает ошибку, как можно чтобы можно было добавлять студента через Spring без аватарки.

StudentController.

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.service.StudentService;
import java.nio.file.FileSystemException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("index");
        return mv;
    }

    // Get All Users
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})

    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setSurname(surname);
            student.setName(name);
            student.setAvatar(studentService.saveAvatarImage(file).getName());
            studentService.saveStudent(student);
        }
        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")
    public String saveEditedUser(
            @RequestParam("id") Long id,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {

        try {

            studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));

        } catch (FileSystemException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "redirect:/error";
        }

        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

        return mv;

    }

}
```

StudentServiceImpl

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.repository.StudentRepository;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;



@Service
@Transactional
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Value("${storage.location}")

    private String storageLocation;

    private StudentRepository repository;

    public StudentServiceImpl() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentServiceImpl(StudentRepository repository) {
        super();
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        repository.findAll().forEach(e -> list.add(e));
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Student getStudentById(Long id) {
        Student student = repository.findById(id).get();
        return student;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean saveStudent(Student student) {
        try {
            repository.save(student);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteStudentById(Long id) {
        try {
            repository.deleteById(id);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override

    public File loadAvatarByFileName(String filename) {

        return new File(storageLocation + "/" + filename);

    }

    @Override

    public File saveAvatarImage(MultipartFile avatarImage) throws IOException {

        File newFile = File.createTempFile(
                avatarImage.getName(),
                "." + avatarImage.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")[1],
                new File(storageLocation));

        avatarImage.transferTo(newFile);

        return newFile;

    }

    @Override

    public Student updateStudent(String name, String surname, MultipartFile avatar, Student targetStudent)

           throws IOException {

        if (name != null && !name.equals(targetStudent.getName())) {

            targetStudent.setName(name);

        }

        if (surname != null && !surname.equals(targetStudent.getSurname())) {

            targetStudent.setSurname(surname);

        }

        File newAvatar = null;

        if(avatar != null){

            newAvatar = saveAvatarImage(avatar);

        }

        assert newAvatar != null;

        String oldAvatarName = targetStudent.getAvatar();

        targetStudent.setAvatar(newAvatar.getName());

       boolean isSaved = saveStudent(targetStudent);

        if (!isSaved) {

            throw new IOException();

        }

        Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(storageLocation + File.separator + oldAvatarName));

        return targetStudent;

    }


}
```

AvatarController

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import adil.java.schoolmaven.service.StudentService;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class AvatarController {

    @Value("${storage.location}")
    private String storageLocation;

    private StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection

    @Autowired
    public AvatarController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }




 @GetMapping(value = "/avatar")
    public void getAvatar(HttpServletResponse response, @Param("avatar") String avatar) throws IOException {
        if (avatar == null || avatar.isEmpty()) {

            return;

        }

        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(studentService.loadAvatarByFileName(avatar)), response.getOutputStream());
    }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void image(@RequestParam String url, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(url);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

AddStudentJSP

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>Home</title>

    </head> 
    <body>

        <div class="add">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>

            <br>
            <center>
                <h1>${headerMessage}</h1>

                <form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addStudent" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <table>

                        <tr>
                            <td><label path="Name">Имя</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label path="Surname">Фамилия</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="surname"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label path="Avatar">Фотография:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="file" name="avatar"/>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Добавить"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form:form>
            </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну... сделать какую-нить дефолтную аватарку, да добавлять её на форму регистрации/создания изначально, и соответственно записывать, ежели другая не указана... обычный же вроде как подход. Ну а коли при создании будет вместо неё указана нормальная - сохранять указанное.

Comment: Можете помочь реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, вы можете убрать полностью из кода проверку на обязательное наличие аватарки. У вас сейчас в методе `addStudent`

```
 if (file != null && !file.isEmpty())
```

Замените на

```
        @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent")
        public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") @NonNull String name,
        @RequestParam("surname") @NonNull String surname,
        @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
        throws IOException {

                    ...
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSurname(surname);
        student.setName(name);

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
        student.setAvatar(studentService.saveAvatarImage(file).getName());
        }

        studentService.saveStudent(student);
```

Либо вы можете вообще в форму передавать Student и возвращать оттуда уже заполненного Student, чтобы в контроллере получить уже готового Student и записывать его в БД. Пусть это будет вам очередным домашним заданием.

Как подсказка, метод должен принимать что-то в виде

```
@ModelAttribute(value = "Student") StudentForm studentform
```

Comment: Для редактирования нужно передавать null тогда, если удалена аватарка и во всех методах, где аватар есть, убрать проверку на null